# override reformatting in forms by webmaster?

Tags: google-chrome, web, jquery

I'm at a website, trying to complete an important form for work.  The webmaster created a form that reformats the phone number to add a "-", but the form does not accept submissions of phone numbers with dashes!  Is there a way to override the stupid site and skip the reformatting?

Comment: Contact the webmaster.

Comment: disable javascript in your browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Just Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+K in Firefox or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+I in Chrome.
Then at the topleft there is an arrow(firefox) or magnifier(chrome). Click on it and hover over the desired element (form field) then click on that. The Inspector should now shows you the code of form element like:

```
<input type="number(Or STH)" name="STH" value="STH" />
```

The **value=""** is the important part. double click on it and enter information between " and " . Then close the inspector and send the form using regular submit button.
**Note:** If there is not a value option you should add it by RightClicking on it and choose `Edit as HTML` then add `value=""` and other stuff ....
CHEERS! And Shame on that nooooooob webmaster ....